# Как вывести в таблицу html отсортированные данные по определенному значению из MySQL средствами PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, вывод

Уважаемые эксперты.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм необходимых действий для достижения следующего результата:

Имеется 2 таблицы в БД:

таблица articles

```
id | name
1  | name_1
2  | name_2
3  | name_3
4  | name_4
...
```

и таблица views

```
id | views | date
1  | 35    | 01.01.2020
2  | 45    | 01.01.2020
3  | 21    | 01.01.2020
4  | 65    | 01.01.2020
1  | 44    | 02.01.2020
2  | 69    | 02.01.2020
3  | 31    | 02.01.2020
4  | 74    | 02.01.2020
1  | 96    | 03.01.2020
2  | 112   | 03.01.2020
3  | 94    | 03.01.2020
4  | 111   | 03.01.2020
...
```

Пока что настроен вывод в таблицу таким образом:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM articles
  INNER JOIN views ON rticles.id = bluch.id ORDER BY date DESC");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
    $table .= "<td>{$row['date']}</td>";
    $table .= "<td>{$row['views']}</td>";
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
```

что, соответственно, при выводе выглядит так:

```
name_1  | 35    | 01.01.2020
name_2  | 45    | 01.01.2020
name_3  | 21    | 01.01.2020
name_4  | 65    | 01.01.2020
name_1  | 44    | 02.01.2020
name_2  | 69    | 02.01.2020
name_3  | 31    | 02.01.2020
name_4  | 74    | 02.01.2020
name_1  | 96    | 03.01.2020
name_2  | 112   | 03.01.2020
name_3  | 94    | 03.01.2020
name_4  | 111   | 03.01.2020
```

Но конечным результат должен получится такой:

```
        |01.01.2020 |02.01.2020 |03.01.2020| ...
name_1  | 35        |44         |96        | ... 
name_2  | 45        |69         |112       | ...
name_3  | 21        |31         |94        | ...
name_4  | 65        |74         |111       | ...
```

То есть идёт выборка по дате, где к каждой из них присваивается нужное число просмотров для конкретного имени.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать, какой алгоритм действий?

Возможно, необходимо сначала первым запросом вывести дату, затем следующим запросом остальные данные, загнать их в массив и прогнать циклом?

Есть какие-либо живые примеры такой реализации? Или хотя бы как правильно обратиться к поисковикам, чтобы найти что-то похожее для визуального примера?
Заранее спасибо за любые подсказки.

Comment: Это PIVOT. MySQL это не поддерживает, формируй на CASE, если список дат статический, или в хранимой процедуре. Или на стороне клиента делай - но сперва получи только список дат, а потом данные с сортировкой `ORDER BY name, date DESC` - для упрощения вывода.

Comment: Лучше за один запрос в БД, получаем данные в таком виде, как сейчас. При этом формируем два массива, в первом сами данные, вида `$arr['name_1']['01.01.2020']=35` второй массив - для формирования списка дат, заполняем его как `$arr2['01.01.2020']=1`. После чего делаем цикл по ключам первого массива - это строки, внутри цикл по ключам второго массива - это колонки